# Any Windows API to configure Notifications and actions in Windows 10?

Tags: c, winapi

Is there any way to configure (on or off) toast notifications and actions in Windows 10 using the Windows API?

I would like to turn off the Security and Maintenance notifications, but not from the registry.

[image]

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Those are user-configured items. There is no API for apps to configure them.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, is there any API to notify Windows when a change is made so the switch can change from on to off?

Comment: Why don't you try to fit in with the system rather than subvert it? What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: I would like to be able to change those settings to all users. Thanks!

Comment: MS expressly wants you not to do that. Why do you wish to subvert the system.